# Is ProvidesFile better than ProvidesPackage or ProvidesClass

Tags: package-writing, documentclass-writing

I want to know which one is suited when I try to create a package file or a class file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the appropriate macro for the appropriate case. That is, use `\ProvidesPackage` for a package (typically a `.sty`), `\ProvidesClass` for a class (a `.cls`) and `\ProvidesFile` for anything else.

One example: `\ProvidesPackage` does additional checking in terms of the name used by the package and that used with `\usepackage`. However, it also stores a package "version" if is it supplied:

```
\ProvidesPackage{<package name>}[<version>]
```

This can be used to make sure loading of packages meet a version criteria, if needed.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I think \ProvidesFile can do the same job.

Comment: @Jiapan: Can you elaborate? Perhaps `\ProvidesFile` *can*, but it's not currently set up that way.

Comment: @Jiapan: See [How do I mark inline code?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863/5764)

Comment: Could you first tell me how to make `\ProvidesFile` monospace like yours in the comment?

Comment: @Jiapan (awfully late on this:) You can mark inline code as such by surrounding it with `\`` on both ends. So `\`<code>\`` is marked as `<code>`.