# Siunitx not running when I change computers

Tags: errors, siunitx

So I am using the `siunitx` package and it is throwing up an error at me when I use it on **my** computer. I know that the error isn't in my code as it has run with no problems on another computer.

The error that it gives me is as follows:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\siunitx\siunitx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3pdfmode.def")
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
               -
l.283   }

?
```

I suspect that there is an error with how my computer is reading \l3kernel as this seems to be where it runs into the issue, however I have tried deleting and redownloading the file and it still throws up this same error.

Comment: The computer on which `siunitx` does not work is probably using an outdated version of the LaTeX kernel together with a newer version of `siunitx`. Do an update. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422176/35864

Comment: To verify that this is indeed a version issue, please post the first six or seven lines of your `.log` file (we will need to know the `LaTeX2e` version, I have `LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5` for example) and your versions of the `expl3` kernel, `l3` modules and `siunitx` (normally this could be done by adding `\listfiles` to the top of your `.tex` file, but this needs the compilation to finish, so you need to force through the errors, not sure if that works here - otherwise you can find the versions in the `.log` *file*, the console output is not enough).

Comment: While I personally don't think that this is a great question I also do not think it should be downvoted immediately. It is a question by a new user and it would be nice to wait a bit before a downvote on a first question and to explain why the question was voted down.

Comment: @moewe thanks for your help, was as simple as not having all my packages updated as I have just updated them and now it runs. I can remove the question now if you guys would prefer?

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate of the question I linked. If you agree you can probably click some button somewhere. If you would rather delete your question you can also do that. Normally I would say that you should not delete your question since duplicates can help other people with their searches, but if you'd rather get rid of a question with negative score, you can also delete it.

Comment: I'll leave it up for now and more experienced users can deal with the question as they see fit (as you noted I am a new user). Once again thanks for your help :)