# Issue with \@ifl@ter and expl3 date style

Tags: packages, expl3

I use MiKTeX on windows and am currently having trouble loading expl3. I recently updated the LaTeX3 packages. The following code is sufficient to generate the error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

To which latex replies:

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   -
l.3     \begin
              {document}
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled both `l3kernel` and `l3packages`. MiKTeX Package Manager reports that `l3kernel` is "Packaged on" 2018-11-22 and "Installed on" 2018-12-05 and that `l3packages` is "Packaged on" 2018-10-18 and "Installed on" 2018-12-05. Maybe the issue has to do with the different dates they are "Packaged on"? I haven't looked at the diff between the two versions.

Anyways, throwing a `\tracingall` in before `\usepackage{expl3}` I get:

```
.... 40 megabyes of text
\@ifl@t@r #1#2->\ifnum \expandafter \@parse@version #1//00\@nil <\expandafter \
@parse@version #2//00\@nil \expandafter \@secondoftwo \else \expandafter \@firs
toftwo \fi 
#1<-\ver@expl3.sty 
#2<-
{\ifnum: (level 1) entered on line 9}
{\expandafter}

\ver@expl3.sty ->2018-11-19 L3 programming layer (loader) 

\@parse@version #1/#2/#3#4#5\@nil ->#1#2#3#4 
#1<-2018-11-19 L3 programming layer (loader) 
#2<-
#3<-0
#4<-0
#5<-
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   -
```

So the issue is that the innermost macro of `\@ifpackagelater` called `\@ifl@ter` is expecting `expl3` to report its date as e.g., `2018/11/19` but it's reported as `2018-11-19` with dashes instead of slashes. For now, I can get code to run by saying:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\save@ifl@ter\@ifl@ter
\def\@ifl@ter#1#2#3#4#5{}  % Temporarily dummy out \@ifl@ter
\usepackage{expl3}         % load package
\let\@ifl@ter\save@ifl@ter % Restore \@ifl@ter
% This would break with the same error as before:
%\@ifpackagelater{expl3}{10/10/2018}{\message{yes}}{\message{no}} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tha LaTeX kernel got updated and replaced the date format from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `dd-mm-yyyy`. You probably should update the LaTeX kernel as well.

Comment: How do I do that? Does mpm have an entry for the latex kernel? Searching for "kernel" the only package that turns up is `l3kernel`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Do you want to answer or should I?

Comment: @HoodChatham It will be listed just as `latex`

Comment: run the update manager as user *and* as admin.

Comment: Probably related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422176/35864

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel got [updated](https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews27.pdf) in April, 2017 to use the ISO 8601 date format `yyyy-mm-dd` instead of [a format Frank invented](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45866688#45866688) :)

You have to update your LaTeX kernel to a newer version so that the date format in `expl3` works. It's always better to update all packages together, or these conflicts might happen.

---

If you can't update for whatever reason, you can use the newer date parser (code tested with an up-to-date (Dec 6th, 2018) `expl3` with the LaTeX kernel of TeXLive 2015):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@ifl@t@r#1#2{%
  \ifnum\expandafter\@parse@version@#1//00\@nil<%
        \expandafter\@parse@version@#2//00\@nil
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \fi}
\def\@parse@version@#1{\@parse@version0#1}
\def\@parse@version#1/#2/#3#4#5\@nil{%
\@parse@version@dash#1-#2-#3#4\@nil
}
\def\@parse@version@dash#1-#2-#3#4#5\@nil{%
  \if\relax#2\relax\else#1\fi#2#3#4 }
\makeatother

\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}

hello

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{nitpick}`You did mean `yyyy-mm-dd`, didn't you? `\end{nitpick}`

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen `\begin{thanks}` Oops, you're right :) `\end{thanks}`

Comment: I *think* the `YYYY-MM-DD` format has been supported since 2017 (https://www.latex-project.org/news/latex2e-news/ltnews27.pdf). `latexrelease` may also help here.

Comment: @moewe Indeed. I hadn't found this `ltnews` before. Thanks :)

Comment: nice to see my inventions being commented on :-) but I made more important ones I hope