# Unknown error "! Missing = inserted for \ifnum. <to be read again> - l.283 }" when typeset

Tags: moderncv

I have to typeset the following code for my CV. The problem is in one laptop Texworks produces the pdf file without errors but in another laptop, it produces the error

```
expl3.sty 283 Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
               <to be read again> 
                    -
               l.283   }
```

The stranger thing is that the line 283 does not exist. Anyway, the code is the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{footmisc}

%% ModernCV themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{green}
\moderncvicons{awesome}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\nopagenumbers{}
%% Character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
%% Adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75, left=2cm,right=2cm,top=1.8cm,bottom=2.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{tikz}
%\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{1cm}
\recomputelengths
\newcommand*{\skypesocialsymbol} {%
  \protect\raisebox{-0.085em}{%
\protect\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.08em,x=0.08em,xscale=0.022,yscale=-0.022, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\protect\path[fill=color2,even odd rule] (487.6550,288.9690) .. controls (489.0610,278.5690) and
  (489.8700,267.9960) .. (489.8700,257.2330) .. controls (489.8700,128.0770) and
  (384.5990,23.3610) .. (254.7670,23.3610) .. controls (241.8630,23.3610) and
  (229.2120,24.4210) .. (216.9010,26.4410) .. controls (194.8280,12.0570) and
  (168.5590,3.6740) .. (140.2880,3.6740) .. controls (62.7660,3.6740) and
  (0.0000,66.4820) .. (0.0000,143.9800) .. controls (0.0000,172.1780) and
  (8.2990,198.3740) .. (22.5900,220.3690) .. controls (20.6650,232.3860) and
  (19.6810,244.6920) .. (19.6810,257.2290) .. controls (19.6810,386.4050) and
  (124.8980,491.1100) .. (254.7660,491.1100) .. controls (269.4230,491.1100) and
  (283.6930,489.6840) .. (297.5620,487.1780) .. controls (319.1120,500.5470) and
  (344.4960,508.3260) .. (371.7080,508.3260) .. controls (449.2100,508.3260) and
  (512.0010,445.5020) .. (512.0010,368.0120) .. controls (511.9980,338.7190) and
  (503.0410,311.4840) .. (487.6550,288.9690) -- cycle(276.7400,429.5960) ..
  controls (202.0340,433.4870) and (167.0750,416.9590) .. (135.0500,386.9050) ..
  controls (99.2850,353.3370) and (113.6520,315.0500) .. (142.7900,313.1040) ..
  controls (171.9120,311.1590) and (189.3980,346.1160) .. (204.9410,355.8400) ..
  controls (220.4650,365.5280) and (279.5340,387.6000) .. (310.7350,351.9320) ..
  controls (344.7100,313.1040) and (288.1410,293.0120) .. (246.6760,286.9300) ..
  controls (187.4730,278.1640) and (112.7260,246.1370) .. (118.5410,183.0230) ..
  controls (124.3580,119.9490) and (172.1230,87.6090) .. (222.3910,83.0470) ..
  controls (286.4680,77.2300) and (328.1820,92.7540) .. (361.1760,120.9070) ..
  controls (399.3270,153.4360) and (378.6840,189.8010) .. (354.3770,192.7270) ..
  controls (330.1660,195.6360) and (302.9730,139.2230) .. (249.5860,138.3750) ..
  controls (194.5590,137.5110) and (157.3690,195.6360) .. (225.3000,212.1590) ..
  controls (293.2660,228.6640) and (366.0500,235.4450) .. (392.2610,297.5760) ..
  controls (418.4900,359.7130) and (351.5070,425.7010) .. (276.7400,429.5960) --
  cycle;
\protect\end{tikzpicture}}%
  ~}
\newcommand{\linkedin}{%
\protect\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.08em, x=0.08em, xscale = 0.3, yscale=-0.28, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,opacity=0.4]
  \begin{scope}[cm={{0.59444,0.0,0.0,0.59444,(346.38938,123.06674)}}]
    \path[fill=black] (380.7408,201.6221) -- (434.0804,201.6221) .. controls
      (438.6572,201.6221) and (442.3417,205.3067) .. (442.3417,209.8835) --
      (442.3417,263.5823) .. controls (442.3417,268.1591) and (438.6572,271.8436) ..
      (434.0804,271.8436) -- (380.7408,271.8436) .. controls (376.1640,271.8436) and
      (372.4794,268.1591) .. (372.4794,263.5823) -- (372.4794,209.8835) .. controls
      (372.4794,205.3067) and (376.1640,201.6221) .. (380.7408,201.6221) -- cycle;
    \begin{scope}[xscale=0.981,yscale=1.019,fill=white]
      \path[fill=white] (402.5597,253.0812) -- (402.5597,223.9631) --
        (393.5086,223.9631) -- (393.5086,253.0812) -- cycle(398.0937,211.3394) ..
        controls (396.6162,211.3680) and (395.4476,211.8021) .. (394.5879,212.6419) ..
        controls (393.7282,213.4818) and (393.2891,214.5561) .. (393.2705,215.8649) ..
        controls (393.2879,217.1476) and (393.7146,218.2145) .. (394.5507,219.0655) ..
        controls (395.3868,219.9165) and (396.5281,220.3581) .. (397.9746,220.3904) ..
        controls (399.5067,220.3582) and (400.7001,219.9165) .. (401.5548,219.0655) ..
        controls (402.4095,218.2145) and (402.8437,217.1476) .. (402.8574,215.8649) ..
        controls (402.8152,214.5561) and (402.3785,213.4818) .. (401.5474,212.6419) ..
        controls (400.7162,211.8021) and (399.5650,211.3679) .. (398.0937,211.3394) --
        cycle;
      \path[fill=white] (409.7910,253.0812) -- (418.8420,253.0812) --
        (418.8420,236.2892) .. controls (418.8400,235.8674) and (418.8594,235.4605) ..
        (418.9015,235.0685) .. controls (418.9437,234.6765) and (419.0231,234.3291) ..
        (419.1397,234.0264) .. controls (419.4635,233.1556) and (420.0068,232.3815) ..
        (420.7698,231.7041) .. controls (421.5327,231.0268) and (422.5375,230.6695) ..
        (423.7843,230.6323) .. controls (425.4081,230.6609) and (426.5817,231.2439) ..
        (427.3049,232.3815) .. controls (428.0282,233.5190) and (428.3830,235.0400) ..
        (428.3693,236.9442) -- (428.3693,253.0812) -- (437.4203,253.0812) --
        (437.4203,235.8724) .. controls (437.3582,231.5975) and (436.3658,228.4316) ..
        (434.4430,226.3748) .. controls (432.5202,224.3180) and (430.0391,223.2958) ..
        (426.9998,223.3081) .. controls (424.5633,223.3851) and (422.6033,223.9309) ..
        (421.1196,224.9456) .. controls (419.6359,225.9604) and (418.5988,226.9826) ..
        (418.0083,228.0123) -- (417.8297,228.0123) -- (417.4129,223.9631) --
        (409.5528,223.9631) .. controls (409.6148,225.2695) and (409.6694,226.6911) ..
        (409.7165,228.2281) .. controls (409.7636,229.7652) and (409.7884,231.4399) ..
        (409.7909,233.2523) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  \end{scope}
\protect\end{tikzpicture}
}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.7cm}   
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{moderncvstyleclassic}{%
\let\oldsection\section%
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\leavevmode\unskip\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\oldsection{#1}}%
}{%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\bigskip
\section{Istruzione e formazione}
\smallskip
\cventry{Nov. 2018--in corso}{Dottorato di Ricerca}{\normalfont{XXXIV Ciclo, Matematica}}{\textit{Universit\`a di Trento}}{}{}
\smallskip
\cventry{12 Aprile 2018}{Laurea Magistrale}{\normalfont{Matematica e Applicazioni (LM-40)}}{\textit{Universit\`a di Camerino}}{Votazione: \textit{110/110 e lode}}{} % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\smallskip
\cventry{22 Luglio 2015}{Laurea Triennale}{\normalfont{Matematica e Applicazioni (L-35)}}{\textit{Universit\`a di Camerino}}{Votazione: \textit{110/110 e lode}}{}
\smallskip
\cventry{5 Luglio 2012}{Diploma di Maturit\`a}{\normalfont{Liceo Scientifico sperimentazione PNI}}{\textit{IIS Costanza Varano}}{Camerino, Votazione: \textit{88/100}}{}
\smallskip
\section{Esperienza professionale}
\smallskip
\cventry{Mar. 2018--Giu. 2018}{Tutor Didattico}{\normalfont{Geometria 1}}{\textit{Universit\`a di Camerino}}{}{Esercitazioni di Geometria 1 per gli studenti del corso di Laurea Triennale in Matematica e Applicazioni (L-35) e in Fisica (L-30)}
\smallskip
\cventry{Ott. 2017--Giu. 2018}{Tutor di Supporto}{Universit\`a di Camerino}{}{}{Attivit\`a di supporto agli studenti del corso di Laurea Triennale (L-35) e Magistrale (LM-40) in Matematica e Applicazioni}
\smallskip
\cventry{Nov. 2014--Feb. 2015}{Tirocinio formativo}{\normalfont{Liceo Scientifico}}{\textit{IIS Costanza Varano}}{Camerino}{Tirocinio curriculare per il conseguimento di 6 CFU previsto dal corso di Laurea Triennale in Matematica e Applicazioni (L-35)}
%% A publications list
\smallskip\smallskip
\section{Competenze linguistiche}
\smallskip
\cvitemwithcomment{Lingua madre}{Italiano}{}
\smallskip
\cvitem{Altre lingue}{Inglese, Livello B1, Certificazione Cambridge English: \textit{PET}}
\cvitem{}{Francese, Livello scolastico, studiato alla scuola secondaria di I grado}
\smallskip
\section{Conoscenze informatiche}
\smallskip
\cvitem{Ottima conoscenza}{Linguaggi MATLAB, C, \LaTeX}
\cvitem{}{Sistema operativo Windows}
\smallskip
\cvitem{Buona conoscenza}{Linguaggio LINGO (\textit{LINDO Systems Inc.})}
\cvitem{}{Pacchetto Microsoft Office}
\cvitem{}{Sistema operativo Linux}
\smallskip
\cvitem{Discreta conoscenza}{Linguaggi Java, JavaScript}
\smallskip
\section{Convegni, Invited talks e Seminari}
\smallskip
\cvitem{Invited talks}{\textit{Viscosity solutions of the $\infty$--Laplace equation}, su invito del Prof. Fabio Bagagiolo (\textit{Universit\`a di Trento}), Trento (Italia), 18 Settembre, 2018.}
\par
\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip
\hfill 25/09/2018
\end{document}
```

I cannot understand where is the error. Please help me because I am becoming crazy.

Thank You

Comment: For my opinion into your latex document there are many private informations.

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes, this is a CV, but this is not the problem

Comment: Works fine for me with pdflatex from texlive 2018. Which tex distribution do you have and which engine do you use for compilation? [l.283 refers to this line in the `expl3` package, not in your document]

Comment: Make sure that all packages involved are up to date. It seems as though your `expl3` is too new for your LaTeX kernel. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422176/35864

Comment: @samcarter I use miktex for compilatione Texworks for the editing.

Comment: @Jeji The best course of action is probably to update your packages, as moewe suggested.

Comment: @moewe Thank you, I update all the packages and now it works.

Comment: line 283 exists in the file where the error was detected. The log file will show which that is, but you did not show that part of the log.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I solved the problem by updating the packages

Comment: sure, I just made the comment as next tine you get a tex error you'll want to know wihch file it is in, and that information is available in the log.