# When I try to load expl3.sty from l3kernel the following error appears "! Missing = instered for ifnum.<to be read again>

Tags: packages, installing, latex3

I have installed and deleted the package several times with Miktek. I am writing in TexMaker editor for Windows. Also it does not work for WinEdt. The code is.

```
\documentclass[article]
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}
111
\end{document}
```

The complete error reads

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
to be read again

l.283 }
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.
)
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
to be read again
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your *entire* LaTeX installation up to date? That error is common if `expl3` is new, but your version of the LaTeX kernel is old. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422176/35864. Run an update in both admin and user mode at least twice. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864.

Comment: `\documentclass[article]` is wrong, please use `\documentclass{article}`

Comment: The syntax error in the question won't give that particular error message ...

Comment: @moewe Do you think we should mark as a dupe here?

Comment: @JosephWright For all I know it is a duplicate. But maybe it is a bit safer to wait for feedback from the OP before closing.

Comment: The update solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: I voted to close the question as a duplicate of the question indicated in the first comment, since the OP confirmed that this solved the issue.