# Freeman-CV compiles in overleaf but not TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, cv

I am trying to use the Freeman CV that can be found here
https://www.latextemplates.com/template/freeman-cv

Although I'm able to run it in Overleaf, I get loads of errors in TeXstudio even when I'm using XeLaTeX.

I would much prefer to be able to run on TeXstudio if possible. Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: If I download the linked `.zip` file, extract it and run XeLaTeX on `cv_3.tex` I get no errors and the output looks sensible enough. What errors do you get when you try to compile the file? Please note that errors in LaTeX can have a knock-on effect, so only check the first few errors and try to resolve them one by one.

Comment: Hi to both and thank you for checking.
I have downloaded and extracted the .zip file in its own folder which now has
cv_3.tex, structure.tex and the folder called fonts.
By running XeLaTeX on cv_3.tex (Tools->Commands->XeLaTeX). The issue persists even if I change the default compiler to XeLaTeX. 
The first few lines appear to be font related:
fontspec.sty->Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \RequirePackage
xparse.sty->Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \RequirePackage{expl3}[2018-04-12]
fontspec.sty -> Missing = inserted for \ifnum. \ProvidesExplPackage

Many thanks!

Comment: The error message suggests your LaTeX is too old for `fontspec`/`expl3`. This should be the same issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422176/35864 and can be resolved by thoroughly updating your TeX system (if you use MikTeX in admin *and* user mode, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864).

Comment: I just updated my packages and it worked like a charm!
I feel like an idiot. Never realised that a few months would make a difference.
Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could be solved with an update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compilation problem with siunitx (returning error regarding ifnum)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422176/compilation-problem-with-siunitx-returning-error-regarding-ifnum)