# A beamer file will not compile

Tags: beamer, miktex2.9

A beamer file that I had created last year will not compile now. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

The log file is long but here is the relevant part:

```
(C:\Users\petrovic\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\beamer\beamerbasetranslator.sty
(C:\Users\petrovic\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\translator\translator.sty
Package: translator 2019-05-31 v1.12a Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
)
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
               -
l.15 \usedictionary
               {translator-basic-dictionary}
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

)
```

I have reinstalled translator and beamer packages, but it did not help. I am using MikTex (which I also updated).

Comment: Ditto here on TL 2019, same version of `translator.sty` as in the provided log. There is no `\ifnum` in my `translator.sty`. @J.Petrovic Did you try removing the `.aux` file?

Comment: Do you have a multi-user MikTeX installation? In that case make absolutely sure that you have updated your system in *both* **Admin *and* User mode** at least twice. The user-installed package `translator` shown in the `.log` is up to date, but if your Admin-installed base system is outdated problems like this might occur. (Can you upload the *complete* `.log` file to a text-sharing website site such as https://pastebin.com/, https://0bin.net/, http://dpaste.com/, https://gist.github.com/, please?)

Comment: @moewe. It worked!

Comment: The issue is structurally the same as the one discussed in [Compilation problem with siunitx (returning error regarding ifnum)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422176/35864) for `siunitx`. Here the 'problematic' package is `translator`, but the rest of the analysis still applies. The problem was solved by a *thorough* system update.