# "! Missing = inserted for \ifnum. <to be read again>" error when trying to cite in TexWorks

Tags: citing, texworks

I am running into the following problem. I am trying to write a document, in which I want to use a footnote citation style. However, whenever I add the package `csquotes` to my code in TeXworks, I get the following error:

`! Missing = inserted for \ifnum. <to be read again> -`

When I remove the package `csquotes` from my code, whenever I use `\cite`, instead of a footnote the entire reference is posted in the text.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


%Citations
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{./library.bib}

\begin{document}

\author{Name}
\title{Time and Earth}
\date{\today}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\include{./chapter01}


\backmatter


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I have tried updating packages, but as far as I can tell they are up-to-date. However, as I am using MikTex on a university computer, I cannot synchronize my repository to an online source automatically. I have downloaded the repository from CTAN manually.

The .bib file is generated by Mendeley and has the following format:

```
    @book{Heidegger2001,
address = {Oxford (UK) {\&} Cambridge (USA)},
author = {Heidegger, Martin},
publisher = {Blackwell Publishers},
title = {{Being and Time}},
translator = {Macquarrie, John and Robinson, Edward},
year = {2001}
}
```

I can leave the `csquotes` package out for now, but I would like to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: You use `citestyle=verbose` - "the entire reference is posted in the text" is intended behaviour. If you want the citation to be in a footnote, use `\autocite` instead of `\cite`.

Comment: As for the error: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted. If there's a problem, it's somewhere in `chapter01` or `library.bib`, and you didn't include those.

Comment: Thank you so much, @DisenchantedLurker. As you might have guessed I am really new to LaTeX, your advice already helped.

I left the `csquotes` package out for now, which does not seem to lead to issues. The content of `chapter1` is simply this: 

`\chapter{From Phenomenology to Hermeneutics}


\autocite{Heidegger2001}. \autocite{Heidegger2001}.`

Comment: The Bibentry has the name "Souza2008" But you say you quote "Heidegger2001" this does not match. Please provide the fitting information. There might be something in the bibentry for heidegger which causes the problem.

Comment: I have changed this in the edit! My question is now mainly why I cannot use the `csquotes` package?

Comment: Without the full `.log` file we can't be certain, but from what I've read so far I'm pretty sure this is essentially the same issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/422176/35864. You seem to have manually installed a new `csquotes` version from CTAN that uses the new ISO date format, but your old MikTeX system does not feature a LaTeX kernel that understands that date format. The usual solution would be not to install any packages manually from CTAN, but to instead install and update packages through the MikTeX Console.